# Magento 2 : How to get product get images for thumbnail?

Tags: magento2, product-images, thumbnail

[image]

Friend please help me how to get **product images and thumbnail images**.

Comment: you need to get Thumbnail product URL from Product collection?

Comment: so sir complete code given i have new developer so very problem understating. in magento code so please given on this code

Comment: I can not understand your question. Can you please specify where you want to show that thumbnail image?

Comment: wait i can explain

Comment: Yes. please explain in details.

Comment: main problem in my local server use in pc

Comment: please check my question and one images uploaded please on this time all product . any trick and code please given this code ,,

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: @pushpendra you want to display same images in all products or you want to display uploaded image in admin grid???? please give some more information so that i can help you out .

Answer (score 7):

You need to inject the **ImageBuilder** class in our block :

```
protected $_imageBuilder;

public function __construct(
    ........
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder $_imageBuilder
    ........
){
    ........ 
    $this->_imageBuilder=$_imageBuilder;
    ........
}

public function getImage($product, $imageId, $attributes = [])
{
    return $this->_imageBuilder->setProduct($product)
            ->setImageId($imageId)
            ->setAttributes($attributes)
            ->create();
}
```

**=> This is default image type :**

```
$imageType = 'product_base_image';  //For getting the base image
$imageType = 'product_small_image';  //For getting the small image
$imageType = 'product_thumbnail_image';   //For getting the thumbnail image
```

Now, **get thumbnail image** in phtml file :

```
<?php
    $imageType = 'product_thumbnail_image'; //for thumbnail image
    $image = $block->getImage($_item, $imageType);
?>

<img src = "<?php echo $image->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
```

Hope, It may be helpful for you !!