# Call to a member function toHtml() on null Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

[image] I am trying to show Product Collection in .phtml file of custom module

```
<a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
    <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
</a>
```

in this line i am getting error as

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function toHtml() on
>   null

anyone please help

i got product Collection By Product ID

```
$this->_itemCollection=[];
        foreach ($collection as $value) {
            $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($value->getProductId());
            array_push($this->_itemCollection, $product);
        }     
        return $this;
```

Comment: `$block->getImage($_item, $image)` returns null. that's what the exception tells you

Comment: add  getImage() function code

Comment: can u place that code??

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> .phtml file

```
<a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
                                <?= $this->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
</a>
```

> getImage() Function in Block File

```
 <?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class file_name extends Template
{
    protected $imageBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $contextImage,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->imageBuilder = $contextImage->getImageBuilder();
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function getImage($product, $imageId, $attributes = [])
    {
        return $this->imageBuilder->setProduct($product)
            ->setImageId($imageId)
            ->setAttributes($attributes)
            ->create();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you its working but i am getting an image small

Comment: which type image you get ?

Comment: image size is very small i

Comment: please attach screenshot

Comment: i dont know how to add image in comment

Comment: post on question

Comment: check question now

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/234745/72911 check this

Comment: getting a solution ???

Comment: not getting any solution yet :(